# Use of GIT for moduli problems

Tags: complex-geometry, gauge-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

Was there an actual use of GIT technics (moment map, Kempf-Ness theorem) in the different proofs of the Kobayashi-Hitchin correspondence (by Uhlenbeck-Yau and Donaldson)? Or this was rather a heuristic to a hardcore analytical proof.

Comment: I just looked at the Uhlenbeck-Yau paper and no GIT ever appears. They construct this metric as a limit, and in showing that this limit exists, they need a uniform bound on the size of something. In showing this bound, they use the stability condition: they show that a consequence of this size blowing up is that there is a subsheaf of $E$ violating the stability condition. This starts on page 17. It has been a while since I looked at the Donaldson paper but again I think it is completely independent of algebraic geometry.